# How can we send a HTTP POST request by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

How can we send a request using the HTTP POST method via javascript...without submitting a form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer to use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - for example:

```
$.post("test.php", function(data){
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Comment: That does require adding jQuery to your system (although if you are going to use AJAX it is much easier if you use some library package)

Comment: Absolutely, but at this point anyone working with JavaScript needs a good reason for NOT using a library such as jQuery.

Comment: Hmmm.. the fact that my Javascript code is almost always far smaller than the massive 24kb (not including plugins) I need to load to use jQuery would be a fairly good reason imho.

Answer (score 9):

[By using AJAX](http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" name="weather" value="sunny" />
</form>

<a href='javascript:submit_form()'>Click here to submit the form</a>

<script language='javascript'>
function submit_form()
{
   var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
   myform.submit()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry just read you put without submitting the form!! You can use Prototype.js, it has a form.serialize method. You can then use a Prototype Ajax call to send the data to the server without submitting the page.